# Pandas .isin() multiple values on row of df1, not in df2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am filtering a dataframe (df1) based on the values in another dataframe (df2). Now, df1 contains some, but not all, rows with multiple values on a row with the' +' since.

For example:

[image]

I have the following which works fine, expect for the row with the '+' symbol.

```
df3 = df1.loc[df1.Project_ID.isin(df2[Project_ID])]
```

I get stuck with figuring out how to include index 3 (110 + 150).

All tips and solutions are appreciated!

Comment: Jello friendo, you want to keep your + row?

Comment: How ID is in this state (110+150)

Comment: Yes I would like to keep that row. The reason the ID is like this, is that it is manually recorded. So, someone could type 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 if they would like to. I know its a bad habit, but unfortunately, that's how it is for me for now.

Comment: What should the erroneous Project Id 110 + 150 equate to?  If you can answer that question you can then update the Project ID column to convert erroneous data to corrected data before doing the rest of your solution.

Comment: df1 contains it as a single value per row (the right way), but df2 doesn't. Thus I would like to select all rows from df1 which have a matching ID with df2.

Comment: I would consider this a cleaning step. To clean it I would do a split(' + ') and then a .explode() to get these on their own rows. The rest of your code should then work as expected